# why if condition is working in a weird way

Tags: c, if-statement, search, linked-list

I am just trying to search the key in a binary search Tree.
Here is what I did.

```
int searchBST(int key,node *root){

    if(root->data == key){
        printf("The key %d is in the tree.\n",key);
        return 1;
    }
    if(root->left != NULL){
        searchBST(key,root->left);
        return 0;
    }
    if(root->right != NULL){
        searchBST(key,root->right);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

In the main function,check if function return 1, if it does, the key is in the tree.

```
printf("Please enter the key value you wish to search for: ");
scanf("%d",&key);
if((searchBST(key,root)) != 1)
    printf("The key %d is not in the tree.\n",key);
```

if the key is not in the tree it will print :

```
The key %d is not in the tree.
```

which is correct. So here comes the weird part, if the key is in the tree, sometime system will print out :

```
The key %d is in the tree.
```

and other time system will print both:

```
The key %d is in the tree.
The key %d is not in the tree.
```

So what can I do to fix it?

Here is my entire code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
// This program will create a binary search tree or a max-heap, as chosen from a menu.
typedef struct BSTNode{
int data;
struct Node *left;
struct Node *right;
}node;
node* getNewNode(int data){
    node *new = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    new->data = data;
    new->left = new->right = NULL;
    return new;
}
void heapPreOrder(int heapRootIndex,int array[],int numOfNodes){
int i = heapRootIndex;
printf("%d\t",array[i]);
if( 2*i+1<numOfNodes)
    heapPreOrder(2*i+1,array,numOfNodes);
if(2*i+2<numOfNodes)
    heapPreOrder(2*i+2,array,numOfNodes);
}
void disLevelOrder(int array[],int numOfNodes){
int i;
for(i = 0;i < numOfNodes;i++){
    printf("%d\t",array[i]);
}
printf("\n");
}
node* insertBST(int data,node *root){
if(root == NULL){
    root = getNewNode(data);
}
else{
    if(data <= root->data){
        root->left = insertBST(data,root->left);
    }
        else if(data >= root->data)
        root->right= insertBST(data,root->right);
    }
    return root;

}

int searchBST(int key,node *root){

 if (!root) return 0;
if (root->data == key) return 1;
if (root->data > key) return searchBST(root->left, key);
return searchBST(root->right, key);
}
void levelOrder(node* root, int level){
if (root == NULL)
    return;
if (level == 1)
    printf("%d\t", root->data);
else if (level > 1)
{
    levelOrder(root->left, level-1);
    levelOrder(root->right, level-1);
}
}
int findHeight(node* root)
{
if (root==NULL)
    return 0;
else
{
    int leftHeight = findHeight(root->left);
    int rightHeight = findHeight(root->right);

    if(leftHeight >= rightHeight)
        return leftHeight+1;
    else
        return rightHeight+1;
}

}
void insertHeap(int key,int numOfNodes,int array[]){
int i,j;
i = numOfNodes-1;
if(i%2 == 1 && array[i] > array[(i-1)/2]){  //if left child is greater than parent
            swap(&array[i],&array[(i-1)/2]);
            for(j = (i-1)/2;j > 0,array[j]>array[(j- 1)/2]; j = (j- 1)/2){
                swap(&array[j],&array[(j-1)/2]);
            }
        }
        if(i%2 == 0 && array[i] > array[(i-2)/2]){//if right child is greater than parent
            swap(&array[i],&array[(i-2)/2]);
            for(j = (i-1)/2;j > 0,array[j]>array[(j- 1)/2]; j = (j- 1)/2){
                swap(&array[j],&array[(j-1)/2]);
            }
        }
}
void searchHeap(int key,int array[],int numOfNodes){
int i;
for(i = 0;i < numOfNodes;i++){
    if(key == array[i]){
        printf("The key %d is in the heap.\n",key);
        return;
    }
}
printf("The key %d is not in the heap.\n",key); 
}
void preorder(node *root){
if(root!=NULL){
    printf("%d\t",root->data);
    preorder(root->left);
    preorder(root->right);
}
}
void swap(int *a,int *b){
int temp;
temp = *a;
*a = *b;
*b = temp;

}
int main(){
int i,j,numOfNodes,key,height;
char choice,option;
node *root = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));       //initialize root;
root = NULL;
printf("Enter the number of nodes in the linked list to be initially created: ");
scanf("%d",&numOfNodes);
int array[numOfNodes];           //store all the data in the array first
printf("Enter the data value to be placed in the node: ");
scanf("%d",&array[0]);
root = insertBST(array[0],root);           //create the root
//root->left = getNewNode(array[0]);
for(i = 1;i < numOfNodes;i++){
    printf("Enter the data value to be placed in the node: ");                 //put each data into array, leave the index 0 empty
    scanf("%d",&array[i]);
}
printf("What do you wish to create a Binary search Tree (B) or a Max-Heap (H)?: ");
scanf(" %c",&choice);
if(choice == 'B' || choice == 'b'){         //if user wants to build a Binary search Tree
    for(i = 1;i<numOfNodes;i++){
        insertBST(array[i],root);
    }
        printf("Binary search tree build successfully.\n");
}


if(choice == 'H'|| choice == 'h'){         //if user wants to build a Max-Heap
        for(i = 1;i<numOfNodes;i++){          //build the max heap
        if(i%2 == 1 && array[i] > array[(i-1)/2]){  //if left child is greater than parent
            swap(&array[i],&array[(i-1)/2]);
            for(j = (i-1)/2;j > 0,array[j]>array[(j- 1)/2]; j = (j- 1)/2){
                swap(&array[j],&array[(j-1)/2]);
            }
        }
        if(i%2 == 0 && array[i] > array[(i-2)/2]){  //if right child is greater than parent
            swap(&array[i],&array[(i-2)/2]);
            for(j = (i-1)/2;j > 0,array[j]>array[(j- 1)/2]; j = (j- 1)/2){
                swap(&array[j],&array[(j-1)/2]);
            }
        }
    }
        printf("Heap successfully created.\n");
    }
while(choice == 'B'||choice == 'b'){
    printf("What do you wish to do?\n");
    printf("Show Preorder Traversal(P)\tShow Level order Traversal(L)\tSearch(S)\tInsert(I)\tQuit(Q)\n");
    printf("Please enter a choice: ");
    scanf(" %c",&option);
        if(option == 'p'||option == 'P'){
        preorder(root);
        printf("\n");
    }
    if(option == 'L'||option == 'l'){
        height = findHeight(root);
        for(i = 1;i <= height;i++){
            levelOrder(root,i);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    if(option == 'S'||option == 's'){     //This is the part I have trouble with
        printf("Please enter the key value you wish to search for: ");
        scanf("%d",&key);
        if((searchBST(key,root)) != 1)
        printf("The key %d is not in the tree.\n",key);
    }
    if(option == 'I'||option == 'i'){       //if user wants to insert a number
        printf("please enter the key value you wish to insert: ");
        scanf("%d",&key);
        insertBST(key,root);
        printf("The key value %d was successfully inserted.\n",key);
    }
    if(option == 'q'||option == 'Q'){
        printf("Thanks for using my program, please rate 100 as feedback! Have a wonderful day :)");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
while(choice == 'H'|| choice == 'h'){
    printf("What do you wish to do?\n");
    printf("Show Preorder Traversal(P)\tShow Level order Traversal(L)\tSearch(S)\tInsert(I)\tQuit(Q)\n");
    printf("Please enter a choice: ");
    scanf(" %c",&option);
    if(option == 'p'||option == 'P'){
        heapPreOrder(0,array,numOfNodes);
        printf("\n");
    }
    if(option == 'L'||option == 'l'){
        disLevelOrder(array,numOfNodes);
        printf("\n");
    }
    if(option == 'S'||option == 's'){
        printf("Please enter the key value you wish to search for: ");
        scanf("%d",&key);
        searchHeap(key,array,numOfNodes);
    }
    if(option == 'I'||option == 'i'){       //if user wants to insert a number
        printf("please enter the key value you wish to insert: ");
        scanf("%d",&key);
        numOfNodes++;
        array[numOfNodes-1] = key;
        insertHeap(key,numOfNodes,array);
        printf("The key value %d was successfully inserted.\n",key);
    }
    if(option == 'q'||option == 'Q'){
        printf("Thanks for using my program, please rate 100 as feedback! Have a wonderful day :)");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

}

Comment: Is this C or C++?

Comment: You need to return the results of your recursion.  Currently when searchBST returns 1 that return value is ignored and the parent returns 0.

Comment: Programmers new to recursion forget to write `return searchBST(key,root->left)`. It's hard to find a duplicate, but I know there's more than one because I remember answering a question just like that (perhaps in another language).

Comment: This is C programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not search the whole binary search tree for a key. You should follow the correct path. That is why you should compare you key with the current root value. If the value is same as key, then this is the output. If the key is less than the root value, you should go to left subtree, otherwise right one.

```
int searchBST(int key, node* root) {
    if (!root) return 0;
    if(root->data == key) {
        printf("The key %d is in the tree.\n",key);
        return 1;
    }
    if (root->data > key) return searchBST(key, root->left);
    return searchBST(key, root->right);
}
```

In your case, you are traversing the whole tree even if you found the key. So that's why sometime you are getting both output.

Comment: Good point! But this one is not working, maybe cuz I am using c

Comment: Why did not it work in C? Can you provide your full code with some data?

Comment: int searchBST(int key,node *root){
    if (!root)
        return 0;
    if (root->data == key) return 1;
    if (root->data > key) return searchBST(root->left, key);
    return searchBST(root->right, key);
}

Comment: In main function:        if(option == 'S'||option == 's'){
            printf("Please enter the key value you wish to search for: ");
            scanf("%d",&key);
            if((searchBST(key,root)) != 1)
            printf("The key %d is not in the tree.\n",key);

Comment: The program crushes when we after entering the key. Sorry, I have no idea how to format this.

Comment: Can you please upload your code and some data so that someone can test?

Comment: The problem is you are calling `searchBST(key, root)`. It should be `searchBST(root, key)`

Comment: I changed it.Thanks, I post my original code up. I have trouble with searchBST function and a part in the main function( I commented that part as // I have trouble with this part)

Comment: I see that you have not used `if (root->data > key)` conditions in your updated code. Try using the code I have provided in the answer and let me know.

Comment: Ok! I upload my code with your answer on the description. It is still crashing after I enter the value with to search for

Comment: What input data did you try with?

Comment: You did not do what I did. I ran your code and used my changes. It worked. For your information, I have edited my code / answer. Just replace your `searchBST` function with my code. Hopefully it'll work.

Comment: So weird, haha. It worked! Thank you! But did you changed your code a little. I really did use your code.

Comment: Plz check your posted code again. You used `searchBST(root->left, key)` but I asked `return searchBST(key, root->left)`. The same is true for `root->right`. You swapped two variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int searchBST(int key,node *root){
    if (!root){
        return 0;
    }
    if(root->data == key){
        printf("The key %d is in the tree.\n",key);
        return 1;
    }
    if(root->left != NULL){
        return searchBST(key,root->left);
        //return 0;
    }
    if(root->right != NULL){
        return searchBST(key,root->right);
        //return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: it should work fine in both c and c++. May I know what is the error message?

Comment: It compiled. I entered : 24,12,51. Three numbers, it works for 24 and 12. But when it comes to 51, it prints out: 51 is not in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Edited Answer-:

1. The issue was regarding the return values. Even if you found the key, in the next iteration loop you are returning value 0. This will be checked in you main function and will be reported as key not found.
2. Second the search was not done in the right links of the node.
3. Duplicate entry in root linked list while adding entries especially the first entry.

Just change your code like this,

```
   int searchBST(int key,node *root){

       int bRet = 1;  /// 1 means error
       if(root->data == key){
           printf("The key %d is in the tree.\n",key);
           bRet = 0;  /// 0 means success
           return bRet;
       }
       if(root->left != NULL){
           bRet = searchBST(key,root->left);
           if(!bRet)
           {
               return bRet;
           }
       }
       if(root->right != NULL){
           bRet = searchBST(key,root->right);
           if(!bRet)
           {
               return bRet;
           }
       }

       return bRet;
  }
```

Main function,

```
  printf("Please enter the key value you wish to search for: ");
  scanf("%d",&key);
  if(0 != searchBST(key,root))
     printf("The key %d is not in the tree.\n",key);
```

Return value 0 means success, any other value including 1 means error/key not found.

I found minor issues as well but i think those should be found in compilation time itself like,

1. int array[numOfNodes]; array declaration needs a const number not a variable.
2. Usage of Node instead of node.
3. Using "new" keyword as a variable.
4. Swap function to be defined above its usage.

Comment: It compiled. I entered : 24,12,51. Three numbers, it works for 24 and 12. But when it comes to 51, it prints out: 51 is not in the list.

Comment: Can you post the complete code so that we can check where it goes wrong?

Comment: Thanks, I post my original code up. I have trouble with searchBST function and a part in the main function( I commented that part as // I have trouble with this part)

Comment: I went through the entire code and found the issue mainly related to search not done in right link. Entry 51 was not searched in the list even though entries are there in the array. Updated my answer as above

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Comment: If the answer is correct then you can upvote this post as the right one. It will help others when they try the same scenario. I think this is a common issue while coding for a search in a linked list.